# css margin seems to refer to body instead of parent?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="slide active" id="sli-0-1">
    <div class="mediaWrapper" id="musWrapper">
        <div class="albumWrapper" id="albumWrap-1">
            .   .   .
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the entire code please refer to [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bHPq2/)

Since I set the height of the child div to 90% in order to compensate for the total of 10% vertical margin, I expected the div to vertically centered within its parent div. As you can see, that is not the case.
I have no clue why - never had this sort of problem before and for some reason I cannot for the life of me figure out what might becausing this behavior. Tried using padding instead of margin with the same height - no changes. Tried to only set `margin-top` to 5% and `height` to 90 - no changes.

This might very well be caused by some stupid mistake of mine, in which case I apologize in advance. If not, I would appreciate if somebody cared to explain this to me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the percentage based `margin-top` value is relative to the width, not the height. You will notice this if you resize the window horizontally - see the margin change relative to the width?

> [**Box Model - 8.3 Margin properties**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties)
>
> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well. If the containing block's width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.

As a work-around, you could absolutely position the element and add `top: 5%` for vertical centering.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/7z3Lr/)

```
div.albumWrapper {
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #a00000;
    margin: 0 2%;
    width: 96%;
    height: 90%;
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
}
```

Comment: Wow this is weird - is it just me, or is this just one of the specification's aspects which make no sense at all? :]
What could be a possible explanation for why it is defined that way?
Anyways, your workaround does the job nicely - at least 'position' works in a way anyone can understand...

Comment: @slagjoeyoco I have no explanation aside from the spec. It *does* seem weird, but I'm sure there are some scenarios where you would actually expect this behavior.

Comment: Alright thank you very much - and yes, such seemingly "strange" behavior might just make sense in certain special situations. Just seems unexpected in common scenarios like this one...

Answer (score 1):

You center the div by adding this line to the css corresponding to the div you intend it to affect

```
#id{margin: 0 auto;}
```

That will center your div in window